# Transferring row from data gridviewview to another datagridview

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datagridview

How do you transfer a row from a `datagridview` to another `datagridview`?

I'm using Entity framework.

Here is what I have tried:

```
 dataGridView1.DataSource = (from movie in movieEntities.Movie.ToList()
                                        join inventory in movieEntities.MovieInventory.ToList()
                                        on movie.MovieID equals inventory.MovieID
                                        join genre in movieEntities.Genre.ToList()
                                        on movie.GenreID equals genre.GenreID
                                        select new 
                                        {
                                            ID = movie.MovieID,
                                            Title = movie.MovieName,
                                            Quantity = inventory.TotalQuantity,
                                            Price = movie.Price,
                                        }).ToList();
```